# display svg images from base64 string in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, base64

I have a base64 String of an image that I want to display on a webpage using react

this is my approach

```
const Picture = ({ data }) => <img src={`data:image/*;base64,${data}`} />
    return (
        (base64String?
            <Picture data={ base64String } /> : <p>loading</p>
        )
    )
}
```

this works perfectly till I use a svg

when I do this

`` <img src={`data:image/svg+xml;base64,${data}`} /> ``

it works only with svg

I want to display all images formats

what am I missing ?

Comment: So you want a picture component that can display both `base64` & `svg`?

Comment: yes if this is possible

Comment: How would a `svg` be accessed, is it coming from server or locally available as an `svg` file? Or you are trying to display/render a `base64` image as an svg? An svg is a different format so an image cannot be used as an svg.

Comment: i'm fetching a base64 String from a database, that string is generated from an `svg` image like this 
`
    file = pic.file.read()
`

`
    coded = str(base64.b64encode(file).decode("utf-8"))
`
where `pic` is a `UploadFile` type 
the coded string is stored to the database

Comment: This `<img src={\`data:image/svg+xml;base64,${data}\`} />` works? I think it's better to have two different components, one for `image` & one for `svg`.

Comment: yup it did but only with `svg`,
I guess I'll have to use two components, thank you anyway